# Structures with mixed packing in MASM?

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, masm

In MSVC, if I want to mix two different structure packing sizes, I could use `#pragma pack()`. For example:

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct libraryAdefine {
  // ...
}

#pragma pack(4)
struct libraryBdefine {
  // ...
}
#pragma pack()
```

In MASM, all I can find for structure packing is the command line parameter `/Zp`. This sets the packing for all structures in the input files, and doesn't allow the same granularity. There is the ALIGN directive (after the structure name) but this aligns the entire structure, not the internal padding -- this does not do the same thing as `#pragma pack`.

How can I accomplish the same in MASM?

Comment: It's assembly language; you normally define the exact struct layout yourself with `dd` / `db` / whatever.  Just put the padding or not as desired.  Or does MASM actually have a feature to implement the C ABI for you and align struct members with padding?

Comment: The /Zp flag, which I described in the question, does exactly that.